# ActionController::ParameterMissing in NamesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Hello there i have been having problems trying to get my Name added onto my index.html via the new.html using form_for kindly look into the code below and correct my code please

**My controller**

def new 
     @post = Name.new
    end

```
def create
    @post = Name.new(post_params)
 if @post.save
redirect_to names_path, notice: "your name was added"
 else
render "new"
 end

end

def post_param

  params.require(:post).permit(:name)
 end
```

**My new.html.erb**

```
<h1> Add your name </h1>
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>   
<%= f.label :name %>     
<%= f.text_field :name %>    
<%= f.submit "Add your name" %>     
<% end %>
```

I am having trouble in this lower part when i click the f.submit (the button that appears in the htlm) it throws me the error.

Comment: please add an actual question. Also more details about the error that is thrown would be helpful.

Comment: If you have created a model called `Name`,then why you are having a `post` instance here in this line `params.require(:post).permit(:name)`?

Comment: Can you post your model? And what is your controller classname is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `new` and `create` methods should look like this

```
def new 
  @post = Post.new #here
end

def create
 @post = Post.new(post_params) #here
 if @post.save
   redirect_to names_path, notice: "your name was added"
 else
   render "new"
 end
end
```

You are confused of using `attribute names` with `model name`.You should be looking at these **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)**.It should help you.

**Update**

As you said you created a **`Name`** model,you shouldn't be creating an **`attribute`** which is same as your **`model name`**.

**Solution**

Either change your `attribute name` or `model name` to some other meaningful name.

Comment: No sir the instance variable is differently named from my model , i did that on purpose

Comment: @user3820090 i didn't get you.

Comment: Sir , i made a model called Names capable of taking in 1 parameter called name

Comment: @user3820090 You shouldn't be creating a model with same name of attribute.

Comment: Previous i was able to use the console and assing values and update and delete them , so could you be more specific as to why i am not supposed to use the attribute name for model Names?